# Navbar color Twitter Bootstrap Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a [Link to Source Code](https://github.com/m4ttclendenen/ecommerce-rails) on GitHub

- I forked a project in order to learn some rails and such
- However, I am having trouble with the simple task of changing the color of the NavBar
- It seems that my changes to `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` have no effect

**I have tried several approaches . . .**

```
...
.....
....... app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
...........
.............


// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #036747;


.navbar {
    background-color: #A4C8EC;
    background-image: none;
}
```

**Approach # 2**

```
...
.....
.......
...........

.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #FFFFFFF;
    border-color: #252525;
}
```

**Approach # 3**

```
...
.....
.......
...........

@navbarBackground: #ffffff;
```

**Thoughts**

- I'm sure i'm using bootstrap or the less variables in the wrong way.
- If you need more of the source code, it's at GitHub -- link at top of
  the page.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried adding `!important`?

Comment: have you tried banging your head against the keyboard? that usually gives me  the same headache.

Comment: @Mallanaga I tried adding `!important` but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mallanaga mentioned in a comment to your post, you could try adding `!important` to the CSS, so:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #FFFFFFF;
    border-color: #252525;
}
```

becomes:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #FFFFFFF !important;
    border-color: #252525 !important;
}
```

Also, double check that you are actually using `.navbar-inverse` in your HTML and not `.navbar-default`.

Comment: Adding `!important` had no effect but my reference to the html was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

make sure your bootstrap files are included in you application.css so the asset pipeline is complete and edits will be made availble!

application.css

```
/*
*
* require bootstrap
*
*/
```